# Sorting not working in IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, internet-explorer

I use 
var a1 = new Array;
 a1.sort(...)

Issue is:
They are multiple columns. If I sort on particular column it is working fine. But
is there a way to sort inner column values

say we sort on col1 and it is sorted properly

but col2 is not sorted for the same value of col1. In Firefox and chrome it is working fine.

```
  col1  col2  
1     5
1     4 
2     3
2     2
2     6
3     7
```

Expected result
    col col 2

```
col1  col2  
1     4
1     5 
2     2
2     3
2     6
3     7
```

Comment: please add your data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort both columns, if the first column is equal then it's sorted by the second.

[`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts by strings, if no callback is available.

> **compareFunction**
>   Optional. Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's [Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Unicode) code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.

```js
var array = [[2, 6], [3, 7], [1, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 2]];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: there is no original data, to check.

Comment: Thanks Nina. In my case there can be more than 2 columns. And the sort code is applicable to any table in my application. Is there any other way to sort instead of a[1]-b[1]. Yes Jai it is taken care in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: what means another way? for strings? then use `localeCompare`.

Comment: var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i<a1.length; i++)
     {
      Fragment.appendChild(a1[i]);
    }

Comment: it depends on your data structure.